# Insert statement in self-join table

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the correct statement to make an insert in a table with a self-join?

If I try to make a classic insert I get the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

This is my insert query:

```
insert into mTable(record_name,self_fk,val, note, ref,insert_date, end_date)
    values('processo prova',0,1,'nota di prova', 'az12345', NOW(), NOW());
```

Comment: Show us your current query.  We're not psychic...

Comment: @MatBailie *You* are not psychic. The constraint fails because you're inserting a `NULL` value on non nullable field.

Comment: @Cid no, as you can see on my query, the fk value is 0

Comment: But is there a 0 in the referenced table?

Comment: @LukStorms No, the table is empty

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` script is very welcome.

Comment: For both/all tables!

Comment: @jarlh both tables?

Comment: i've added the create statement

Comment: You need to insert first in the **processo** table row for process 0, after that you can insert in the table **mTable** the other process

Comment: Maybe you should use `null` instead of `0`, but without the actual definition, we can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `INSERT` query, you are referencing to a `foreign key` (the id 0) that doesn't exist -> constraint fails

I saw in your edits, before you roll it back, your `CREATE TABLE` script.

The field containing the reference to the parent was created this way :

```
`id_processo_padre` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

I suggest you to edit this field to make it nullable :

```
ALTER TABLE `mTable` MODIFY `id_processo_padre` int(11) NULL;
```

This will allow you to `INSERT` the first top level parent (or **any** top level parent)

```
insert into mTable(record_name, self_fk, ...)
            values('processo prova', NULL, ...);
--                                   ^--^----------This
```

---

Test it yourself :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT(6) NULL,
  someData VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES test(id)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (default, null, "parent"),
                        (default, 1, "child1_1"),
                        (default, 1, "child1_2"),
                        (default, 3, "child2_2");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.someData AS "My parent's name" FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

**Output**

```
| id  | parent_id | someData | My parent's name |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---------------- |
| 1   | null      | parent   | null             |
| 2   | 1         | child1_1 | parent           |
| 3   | 1         | child1_2 | parent           |
| 4   | 3         | child2_2 | child1_2         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ak7jspPsw7D6JXXmsKauxk/1)